# Swagger giving a 403 error locally

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, iis-express

Recently I've had a problem where all my projects using ASP.Net Core with Swagger give a 403 error when trying to access them through a browser locally. This happened overnight and seems to effect all Swagger projetcs when run using IIS Express.

I have tried:

- Different browsers (Firefox/Chrome/Edge)
- Different operating systems
  (Windows 10 / 7)
- Different versions of Visual studio (2017 and 2017
  preview)
- Different machines
- Going back to an old branch I know was
  working

All give the same result. The issue doesn't seem to stop the API from working and when it is deployed to an Azure app service the Swagger UI appears with no issues. Any idea what the problem could be here?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0 Check the sub status first.

Comment: Does IIS Express give a substatus? The link only mentions "IIS 7.0, IIS 7.5, and IIS 8.0" - how would I view it?